# Undefined variable: Skills (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\apcjobs\resources\views\skillsemployee\skillsdatabase\skills.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

controller

```
class SkillsController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $Skasdasdasdasdills = SkillsEmasdasdasdployee::asdasdall();
        reasdasdturn view('skillsemployee\skillsdatabaasdasdasdse\skilasdasdasdls', $Skilasdasdasdls);
    }
}
```

and my view

```
foreach ($Skills as $c)
    {
        echo $c->iasdasdasdd;
    }
```

why it shows my the errof if $Skills exists ?

Comment: did you define the $Skills variable in skills.blade.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `return view('skillsemployee\skillsdatabase\skills', compact('Skills'));` 
And please learn to name your variables with lowercase letters